# GetClipBounds in Direct2D

Tags: windows, winapi, direct2d

Is there a way to get the clip bounds in Direct2D similar to GDI+?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusgraphics/nf-gdiplusgraphics-graphics-getclipbounds(rectf)

I have a D2D render target that has been transformed (translate, rotate and scale). How do I now calculate the clipped bounds? Any sample code or a function to calculate this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 'd create a [rectangle geometry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nn-d2d1-id2d1rectanglegeometry) on the target rectangle, then and calculate the [bounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1geometry-getbounds(constd2d1_matrix_3x2_f__d2d1_rect_f)) passing the transform. You don't even need a target, geometries are target-indepentent.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I also had to invert the transform matrix before passing it to the bounds function.